# APEX: Use a dynamic string to create an instance of a class

Tags: apex, class, dynamic, type

I have an `abstract` class called `Process` that I extend to create a list of processes (`List<Process>`);  each in relation to an object. For now everything works as expected but I'm really hoping to create a very dynamic approach to these processes.

For example I also have a `Process__c` custom object, and with a SOQL statement I can get a list of all the `Process_c` records I need for a given context. These records contain the **`String` name of a class that I want to instantiate**, but for the life of me I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I've tried something like the following:

```
String s = 'Account';
List<Process__c> activeProcesses = [SELECT Name FROM Process__c WHERE Active__c = TRUE AND Object__c = :s];
List<String> processNames = Utils.Data.Convert.stringList(activeProcesses, 'Name');

Type t = Type.forName('Process');
List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();
for(String processName : processNames){
    Process p = t.newInstance(processName);
    processes.add(p);
}
```

> The error I'm getting when attempting this is:

`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Type].newInstance(String)`

I really hope the harsh reality isn't that this is just not possible but if it is I need to know that as well, so any insight you have with this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes thank you very much. Someday this may lead to a free public release, if so I'll be sure to give thanks there as well!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your strategy will work, but your constructor *must* contain no parameters, and the same goes for your `newInstance()` call. You pass the name of the `Type` you want to construct into the `Type.forName` method.

```
Type customType = Type.forName('SomeClass');
SomeClass instance = (SomeClass)customType.newInstance();
```

You probably will want to implement an `interface` here as well. Something like:

```
public interface IProcess { void execute(); }
public class Process1
{
    public Process1()
    {
        // instantiation logic
    }
    public void execute()
    {
        // execution logic
    }
}
```

You would use the above as follows:

```
IProcess instance = (IProcess)Type.forName('Process1').newInstance();
```

You don't even really need to cache it for simple cases:

```
(IProcess)Type.forName('Process1').newInstance().execute();
```

Comment: How do I then pass it the extended class name that I want if not through there?

Comment: @Xtreme You pass it into `Type.forName`.

Comment: Awesome, got my temp example to work! Now to plug it into my project. Thanks so much!

Comment: Nice. Be sure to test it with a variety of `Profiles`, I had to work through some access issues last time I implemented something dynamic like this.

Comment: Thanks for that. Also the `Process` class is an `Abstract` because I have more than just method signatures defined in the class. From what I understand an `Abstract` is a type of `Interface` as well right?

Comment: No, they're not really the same thing per se. But here they are functionally quite similar in that they let you define object behavior.

Answer (score 16):

If you do have a need to pass parameters to the dynamically created class, a way to do that is to create the class by using `JSON.deserialize`:

```
Type t = Type.forName('Process');
Process p = (Process) JSON.deserialize('{}', t);
```

so that if the class has e.g. fields `x` and `y`:

```
public virtual class Process {
    Integer x;
    String y;
}
```

you can set values in them like this when the instance is created:

```
// This could come from e.g. a configuration custom setting
String configClass = 'ProcessSubClass';
String configParameters = '{"x": 34, "y": "Hello world"}';

Process p = (Process) JSON.deserialize(configParameters, Type.forName(configClass));
```

assuming `configClass` is a sub-type of `Process`.

Comment: I'll have to remember this for the next time I have a project that involves using `Type.forName()`. I had previously resigned myself to the thought that I would always need to create a separate method to mirror a constructor if I needed to provide anything to a dynamically instantiated class. My only potential concern is with the performance of `JSON.deserialize()`. Have you run any tests to characterize the performance?

Comment: @DerekF No I'm afraid I haven't; typically used this for limited numbers of configuration objects where the performance has been good enough.

Comment: @DerekF I wondered about performance as well. Note too that you don't *need* to get the type dynamically. You can do `JSON.deserialize(payload, ProcessSubClass.class)` just as easily as using `Type.forName` for that second parameter.