# Type.ForName is not working in apex

Tags: apex, type

I have an implementation where i'm storing class name in custom metadata & trying to instantiate the class in apex using `Type.forName` but getting:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void forName(String)
> from the type String

The line causing this issue is something like this

```
 list<customMetadata__mdt> result = [SELECT MasterLabel,Id,ClassName__c FROM customMetadata__mdt];

 Type classname=Type.forName(result[0].ClassName__c);
```

Comment: This is usually an issue of _name shadowing_. Do you have a variable in scope called `type`? Do you have an Apex class anywhere in your org called `Type`?

Comment: Check this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137936/apex-use-a-dynamic-string-to-create-an-instance-of-a-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard `Type` is a part of the standard `System` namespace. Check it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_type.htm)

In order, to fix a problem, where you have a local variable with the same name, you can explicitly mention, that it is a class from a `System` namespace. In your example that should be.

```
List<customMetadata__mdt> result = [SELECT MasterLabel,Id,ClassName__c FROM customMetadata__mdt];

Type classname = System.Type.forName(result[0].ClassName__c);
```

---

Moreover, I recommend you to use a method [forName](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_type.htm#apex_System_Type_forName_2) that is accepting two parameters. First - namespace of where this `Type` is located. That would allow you to omit confusion, if this code will be running on a org with a namespace:

```
List<customMetadata__mdt> result = [SELECT MasterLabel,Id,ClassName__c FROM customMetadata__mdt];
    
Type classname = System.Type.forName(null, result[0].ClassName__c);
```

Comment: Thanks, Yeah there was a type local variable. This helped.